# TypeScript declaration merging not works?

Tags: typescript

I want to add a new member to an existing interface. But typescript keeps throwing errors.

```
// foo.js
export interface IOption {
    xOffset: number
}
```

```
import {IOption} from 'foo';

// I want to add a `yOffset` to IOption, but this won't work.
// I got an error: `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'IOptions'`
interface IOption {
    yOffset: number
}
```

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the interface for the same module.

## Fix

```
import {IOption} from 'foo';

declare module 'foo' {

    interface IOption {
        yOffset: number
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot extend an existing interface, but you can create another one with the same name, by using a trick:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';

interface IOption extends foo.IOptions {
    yOffset: number
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right. If I had to do it with `extends`, then what's the point of the declaration merging?? What's the use case of it? I thought the declaration merging is something just like Ruby's class reopening, but seems like it's not. So what it is then?

Comment: I think this answer wasn't understanding your question correctly, as you're not trying to extend it, you're trying to merge declarations.  Documentation on @basarat's correct answer can be found in the "Module Augmentation" section of this link:
 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html